# Program to summarise grades not compiling

Tags: java, debugging, compilation

I'm getting compile error with this program language is Java.
Its a simple program to take in grades and print stats back for the user... Any help would be great...

Where getting further now 
here are the error outputs:

C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:60: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
            for (int [] grade : studentGrades )
                                ^
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:63: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
                if (grade < lowGrade)
                          ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:64: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
                lowGrade = grade ;
                           ^
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
        for (int[] grade : studentGrades)
                           ^
  symbol:   variable studentGrades
  location: class SummariseGrades
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:85: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
            for (int[] studentGrades : grade)
                                       ^
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:88: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
                if (grade > highGrade)
                          ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:89: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
                highGrade = grade;
                            ^
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:123: error: variable grades is already defined in method outputBarChart(int[][])
            for (int [] grades : studentGrades)
                        ^
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:123: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
            for (int [] grades : studentGrades)
                                 ^
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
            ++frequency [ grade / 10 ];
                          ^
  symbol:   variable grade
  location: class SummariseGrades
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.printf ("Student %2d", student + 1);
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable student
  location: class SummariseGrades
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:168: error: cannot find symbol
        for ( int test: grades [ student ] ) // output student grades
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable student
  location: class SummariseGrades
C:--11\SummariseGrades.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
        double average = getAverage (grades [ student ] ) ;
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable student
  location: class SummariseGrades
13 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1

******Here is the code

```
  public class SummariseGrades
 {
    public static void main (String[]args)
   {
    //2d array of student grades
    int [][] gradesArray =
    { { 87,96,70 },
      { 68,87,90 },
      { 94,100,90 },
      { 100,81,82},
      { 83,65,85},
      { 78,87,85},
      { 85,75,83},
      { 91,94,100},
      { 76,72,84},
      { 87,93,73}  };

    //output grades array
    outputGrades ( gradesArray );

    //call methods getMinimum and getMaximum
    System.out.printf ("\n %s %d \n %s %d \n \n",
    "Lowest grade is", getMinimum ( gradesArray ),
    "Highest grade is", getMaximum (gradesArray ) ) ;

    //output grade distribution chart of all grades on all tests
    outputBarChart (gradesArray);

} //end main





//find minimum grade
  public static int getMinimum (int grades [][])
{
    //assume first element of grades array is the minumum
    int lowGrade = grades [0][0];

    //loop through rows of grades array
    for (int [] studentGrades : grades )
    {
        //loop throught the columns of current row
        for (int [] grade : studentGrades )
        {
            //if grade less than lowGrade, assign it to lowGrade
            if (grade < lowGrade)
            lowGrade = grade ;
        } //end inner
    }//end outer

    return lowGrade;  // returns lowest grade
  } //end method getMinimum





    //find maximum grade
    public static int getMaximum (int grades [][])
    {
    //assume first element is the largest in array
    int highGrade = grades [0][0];

    //loop through rows of the grades array
    for (int[] grade : studentGrades)
    {
        //loop through columns of the current row
        for (int[] studentGrades : grade)
        {
            //if grade greater than highGrade then assign it to highGrade
            if (grade > highGrade)
            highGrade = grade;
        } //end inner
    } //end outer

    return highGrade;  // return highest grade

} //end method getMaximum



  //determine average grade for particular set of grades
  public static double getAverage (int[] setOfGrades )
  {
    int total = 0;  // initialise total

    //sum grades for one student
    for (int grade : setOfGrades)
    total += grade;

    //return average of grades
    return (double) total / setOfGrades.length;
    } //end method for getAverage

    //output bar chart displaying overall grade distribution
    public static void outputBarChart (int grades[][])
   {
    System.out.println ("Overall grade distribution:");

    //stores the frequency of grades in each range of 10 grades
    int[] frequency = new int [11];

    // for each grade in the grade book, increment the appropriate frequency
    for (int [] studentGrades : grades)
    {
        for (int [] grades : studentGrades)
        ++frequency [ grade / 10 ];
    } //end outer

    //for each grade freq, print bar in chart
    for (int count = 0 ; count < frequency.length ; count++)
    {
        //output bar label
        if (count ==10)
        System.out.printf ( "%5d: ", 100);

        else
            System.out.printf ("&02d-%02d: ",
            count * 10, count * 10 + 9 );

        //print bar of asterisks
        for (int stars = 0 ; stars < frequency [ count ] ; stars++)
            System.out.print ("*");

        System.out.println();  //start a new line of output

    } //end outer for loop

  } //end method for outputBarChart

  //output contents of the grades array

   public static void outputGrades ( int grades [][])
   {
    System.out.println ("The grades are:\n");
    System.out.print ("             "); //align column heads

    // create a column heading for each of the tests

    for (int test = 0 ; test < grades [0].length; test ++)
        System.out.printf ("Test %d ", test + 1);

        System.out.println ("Average");  //student average column heading

    //create rows and columns of text representing array grades

    for (int student = 0 ; student < grades.length ; student ++);
    {
    System.out.printf ("Student %2d", student + 1);

    for ( int test: grades [ student ] ) // output student grades
        System.out.printf ("%8d", test );

    // call method getAverage to calculate the student's average grade
    // pass row of grades as the argument to getAverage
    double average = getAverage (grades [ student ] ) ;
    System.out.printf ("%9.2f \r", average );

  } // end outer for
 } // end method outputGrades
} // end class Summerise Grades
```

Comment: Identifying the programming language used is somewhat important, as many more than one exist.

Comment: Please update with the error that you are receiving also.

Comment: Probably wrong # or placement of `()` but I'm just guessing since you didn't tell us what the error was. And.... for once my guess was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy pasted your code into an IDE and got a `Syntax error on token ")", delete this token` error (in the future, please post your exact compiler error)

This is because you have an extra `)` at the end of the first line of the `System.out.printf` call:

```
 System.out.printf ("\n %s %d \n %s %d \n \n",
    "Lowest grade is", getMinimum ( gradesArray ),
    "Highest grade is", getMaximum (gradesArray ) ) ;
```

Comment: I have fixed that part with your help. Thank you Mr Zorn